# if statement for indexing dataframes pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

so this is a library management system, it has a book issuing function but the problem is if the book is already issued and we issue it again it overwrites the previous user who issued it so i wanna add an if statement that if availablity ="No" then print "not available"
here the book user input will be the row and "Availablity" is the column structure = pd.DataFrame(df)" and df is my csv file

```py
def issue_book():
    global structure
    global df
    print('------------------------------')
    print(structure)
    print('------------------------------')
    print('')
    book=input("What book do you want to issue?: ")
    issue_person=input("Who do you want to issue the book to: ")
    if structure['Book Name'].str.contains(book).any():
        structure.set_index('Book Name', inplace=True)
        structure.loc[book,'Issue Date']=today
        structure.loc[book,'Availability']='No'
        structure.loc[book,'Issued To']=issue_person
        structure.loc[book,'Return Date']=return_time
        structure.reset_index(inplace=True)
        print('------------------------------')
        print('Book issued Successfully')
        print('------------------------------')

    else:
        print('------------------------------')
        print("Wrong Input, Enter book index again!")
        print('------------------------------')
        issue_book()
```

Comment: What is it that you are stuck on that you can't add this `if` statement? I'm thinking like `if structure.loc[structure['book name'] == book, 'Availability'] = 'No': or something?

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't understand problem. First you should get books which have correc title and later work with this dataset and use `for`-loop with `if/else`, or split on two groups - with `'Availability' == 'No'` and `'Availability' != 'No'`, and then you can run different code for different group.